# How do I retrieve Facebook account last login locations with ip?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

In Facebook under security tab we can see from where our Facebook account was last logged in or from what location Facebook messenger was opened .

I want to build an app for Facebook using Facebook php api to pull the information for a user so he can see it on a map.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that information is not available with the api.

Comment: @luschn  so no other source / or approach either ?

Comment: of course not. that would be a pretty large security issue anyway, because a third party app would be able to access the data. if it´s not possible with the api, forget about it.

Comment: Ok cool but When that tab is open a plugin/ extension  can extract information from the page !

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, so no, that is not a solution. even if it would be a solution, you need to show what you have tried so far on stackoverflow ;)